# Issues with Codable struct and Measuments<Unit>

Tags: json, swift, xcode

Can't figure out how to save to JSON standard units of the Dimension class, I have a struct:

```
struct Item: Hashable, Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var price: Int
    var unit: Measurement<Unit>
}
```

Xcode doesn't throw any errors so I'm assuming Measurement can be encoded? I can't really make it working and save a json, and how should my json data look like if I want to load the struct with a test json?

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test",
        "price": 195,
        "unit": ???
    }
]
```

The idea is that I operate with the standard Dimension class that has all units I need (kg/g/L/ml) instead of creating my own class and describe all units from scratch.
Is it possible to have a JSON with "unit": "kg" that then will match a standard UnitMass.kilogram automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: What actually is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me this actually works with this (simplified) example:

```swift
struct Item: Codable {
    
    var name: String
    var unit: Measurement<Unit>
}

let json =
"""
{
    "name": "Test",
    "unit": {
        "value": 12,
        "unit": {
            "symbol": "ml"
        }
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let item = try JSONDecoder().decode(Item.self, from: json)
```

yields the correct result. You can replace the unit symbol with anything you like (kg, g, ml, e.t.c)

Comment: Wonderful, my json was incorrect but using yours as an example I can see it actually works... just need to test if the decoded data then can be used in the code as Unit type. Thank you.